# No subscribers for events posted from background service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I post `EventBus.getDefault().post(new SendPlayer(player));` from a services, which is running in non main thread:

```
<service
  android:name=".player.PlayerService"
  android:process=":player"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true">
</service>
```

I expect to receive even in my fragment:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN) public void onEvent(SendPlayer event) {
  Log.w("mcheck", "onEvent");
}
```

However, I get message:
`D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class yarh.com.tryexo.player.SendPlayer`.

Events are delivered only if I remove `android:process=":player"`.

Is it a bug or I misunderstood flow of posting events between background thread and main thread?

Comment: just use `bound service` pattern (most likely using AIDL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `process` attribute causes your `PlayerService` to run in its own separate process pretty much like a totally different app.

This is like trying to fire an event in one app from another totally different app. You will need to find a different way to communicate with your service or place all components that need to communicate in the same process.